# iOS: UIView Animation Refactoring

Tags: ios, refactoring, core-animation, grand-central-dispatch, uiviewanimation

Whilst playing around with `UIView animation`, I came across a situation where I think some refactoring is needed:

The following views whose `opacity` are initially set to `0.0f`.

Ex:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^
                 {
                     firstView.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                      animations:^
                      {
                          secondView.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
                          firstView.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
                      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished)
                      {
                          [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                           animations:^
                           {
                               thirdView.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
                               secondView.layer.opacity = 0.0f;

                           }
                           completion:^(BOOL finished)
                           {
                               thirdView.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
                           }];
                     }];  
                }];
```

All 3 views are just subclass of `UIView`'s, which are added as subviews of the main view.

This simply animates the opacity of the first view to 1.0f and then that of the second view, and then that of the third view.

Simple. Nothing special here.

My Question is:

What if I had more views, let say 100, that I wanted to perform the same action (same sequence of animation), this block of code would expand and expand.

So for the sake of refactoring and being adhered to good practice of writing code, I thought may be this could be done with less code via the use of a method and perhaps a loop.

Could you enlighten me on this in regards to refactoring; in addition, would `dispatch_apply` be useful here along with the refactoring process if a loop is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to animate 100 images, you would probably want to use 2 views and load alternating images into each one. I recently created a sample app on github that does exactly that:

[Animating UIImages with cross-fade opacity changing](https://github.com/DuncanMC/Animate-Img)

Comment: A very clever solution that scales well with complexity. +1

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, thanks. (for the kind words and the upvote.)

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for sharing. I will go take a look at it and see if I could learn something from it in terms of animation refactoring. +1 in advance.

Comment: @DuncanC I went through the program line by line. The animation arose my curiosity: is it possible to transform the image programmatically like that without using a series of images? Is there a name for this technique? I know it is out of scope here; I just thought I would ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig, what kind of transformation are you talking about? You don't say what your sequence of images is. If you're talking about the face morphing images in the demo app, then the answer is "of course."

Comment: @DuncanC That's what I meant - the face morphing. I wondered if there is a name for this kind of technique. No, the sample above in my question I never intended to do any morphing; it was about refactoring. But after running your project here, it got me curious about this sort of technique. I think it's marvelous to be able to manipulate the pixel of an image like this. My guess would be that we would first need to get a bitmap of the image and access the pixels in an array but that's all I could think of.

Comment: @Unheilig, you should click the link and download the app, FaceDancer, from the app store. It's free. It uses a technique known as mesh warping. It takes an image of a face, finds faces in it, then maps that image into an OpenGL texture. Then it maps that texture onto a rectangular grid (50x50) Finally, it pushes around the points on the grid, and then draws the texture onto the distorted grid, compressing some parts of the image and then stretching out other parts. If you're running FaceDancer and double-tap with 2 fingers on an image it shows the grid it's using.